# Python scan txt file for string then write to Excel then continue for next match

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

thanks for reading this firstly.  I normally code in Perl, but I am moving to Python and I am trying to muddle through with the following script.

I have a large text file which has the following format...

```
2014 Apr 11  07:14:03.155  sectorBLAH
   Interestingcontent
   Interesting1 = 843
   Interesting2 = 56
   ReallyInteresting = 1
   Interesting3 = N/A

2014 Apr 11  07:14:04.189  sectorBLAH
Interestingcontent
   Interesting1 = 7843
   Interesting2 = 656
   ReallyInteresting = 0
   Interesting3 = 5
```

This sequence continues for some time. 
What I am hoping to do is create an xls file which is populated as I go through this long list.  Basically I am hoping to find "ReallyInteresting" string and capture it's value "0" or "1" and then send this value to column 2 in xls.  Meanwhile in column 1 in the xls I hope to post the timestamp associated to the output from the "ReallyInteresting" string group, a bit like this...

```
Column1         
07:14:03.155        
07:14:04.189
...     

Column2
1
0
....
```

I have written the following code, but I think my rows and columns are being overwritten.

```
import re
import xlwt

f = open("C:\Results\Logging.txt", "r")
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("New Sheet 1")
sheet2 = book.add_sheet("New Sheet 2")
searchlines = f.readlines()
searchstrings = ['ReallyInteresting =']
timestampline = None
timestamp = None
f.close()
a = 0
tot = 0
row1 = 1
row2 = 1

while a<len(searchstrings):
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        for word in searchstrings:
            if word in line:
                timestampline = searchlines[i-4]
                for l in searchlines[i:i+1]: print timestampline,l,
    row1 +1         
    sheet1.write(0, row1, timestampline)
    for i in line:
        str = timestampline
        match = re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}', ' ')
        if match:
            print '\t',match.group(),'\t',searchstrings[a]
        row2 +1
    sheet2.write(0, row2, searchstrings[a])
        print
        print
        tot = tot+1
        break

    print 'total count for', '"',searchstrings[a],'"', 'is', tot
    tot = 0
    a = a+1

book.save("New_Excel.xls")
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again,
MikG

Comment: Correct your code indentation, after the line `sheet2.write(2, row2, searchstrings[a])` it gets indented what is not allowed there. The line itself is likely to be indented to the right, but I do not want to edit code of your question.

Comment: Also your `Logging.txt` has inconsistent indenting, the line `Interesting content` is on two different levels. If you want good answer, provide good question, so far it is not able to help you. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably here:

```
row1 +1
```

It returns (to nowhere) incremented value of row1, but `row1` is untouched.

change it to

```
row1 += 1
```

Apply the same to `row2` too.

Comment: Hi Jan,I tried your suggestion but with no luck, I think i'll have to review the code again